# Select A row from Jtable based on Jtextfield Input

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtextfield

I have a JTable displaying contents in this format:

```
Part Number    Quantity   Price
SD1131            7       1,000
SD6534            6       2,000
```

On the same frame I have a JTextfield(txtNo). I need it such that when the user types the Part Number on the JTextfield, the corresponding record is selected on the JTable. So far I have only been able to select records based on the row number like this:

```
txtNo.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {

                int index1 = 0;
                int index2 = 0;
                try {
                    index1 = Integer.valueOf(txtNo.getText());
                    tbStore.setRowSelectionInterval(index2, index1);
                } catch (Exception ae) {
                    ae.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

How can I implement the same method to select the JTable row based on the input of the JTextfield?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to find the item in your table for which the part number is equal to the part number entered in the textfield. Steps to take:

- Read the contents of your textfield
- Search the index of the matching element in the `TableModel`
- Convert that index to the corresponding row index in the `JTable` using the `convertRowIndexToView` method (to take in account sorting, filtering, ... )
- Use the `setRowSelectionInterval` method of the `JTable` to select that row

As an alternative, you can use the `JXTable` of the SwingX project which has searching capabilities built-in. The SwingX library also includes a component which allows to search such a `JXTable` (see `JXSearchPanel` and `JXSearchField`)

Answer (score 2):

You should interrogate the TableModel and find out which row contains the part number you are looking for:

```
for(int i=0;i<tbStore.getRowCount();i++) {

    // 0 is for the column Part number
    if(tbStore.getValueAt(i, 0).equals(Integer.valueOf(txtNo.getText())) {
        tbStore.setRowSelectionInterval(i, i);
        break;
    }
}
```

Caveats: I haven't tested this code, but it should give you at least the basic idea.

Comment: @Stanley basically works but depends of `JTables` setting, `XxxTableModel`, `Listeners`, `RowSorter`, `RowFilter`, no idea in your case, for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), see `convertRowIndexToView` and `setRowSelectionInterval` in the answwer by (`@Robin`)

Comment: @mKorbel good catch! missing row index conversion might be the problem

Comment: @mKorbel indeed my answer did not take into account sorting and filtering. Nicely spotted!

Comment: you might consider editing the _code_ to make it correct :-) Personally, I would loop in view coordinates (as opposed to model coordinates) as selection belongs into the view realm anyway, then there would be no need for the conversion.

Comment: @kleopatra depends a bit on the use case. You can use a search to filter and select, and when changing the query I would expect to start searching the whole model again. But as said, it depends on the use case whether I would loop over the view or the model

Comment: @Robin agreed, just stated my personal preference in this particular use-case which appears to be selection-only :-)